# Casting a Derived class pointer to a Base class reference

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reference, derived-class

I have a quick question regarding Base->Derived class relationships and casting. Like the title says, I need to cast a pointer to a derived class to a reference to a parent class. Currently, I have this code:

`IIcon& retval = static_cast<IIcon&>(*obj)`, where obj is a `AtlasTexture*` object, which is a derived class of `IIcon`.

I am still a little foggy on the many different types of casts in C++, and was wondering if this would work, and if there was a more efficient or safe way to do this same thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write simpler

```
IIcon& retval = *obj;
```

Comment: Is this valid for any time you are casting a derived class to a parent type?

Comment: @sm81095 Yes, it is valid.